# Continuity of a composition map between Holder spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, holder-spaces

Let $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R})$, $0<\alpha<1$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded domain.

Is it true that the map $\Phi:C^{0,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})\to C^{0,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$ defined by
\begin{eqnarray}
\Phi(u):=\varphi\circ u
\end{eqnarray}
is continuous? Or are there any props similar to this?

Comment: What do you require on $u$?

Comment: How to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}[\varphi\circ(u+h)-\varphi\circ u]_{\alpha}=0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true, and here is an approach: 
$$
\varphi\circ(u+h)-\varphi\circ u = h \int_0^1 \varphi'\circ(u+th)\,dt 
$$
On the right, the Hölder norm of the integral is controlled by the derivatives of $\varphi$ and the Hölder norm of $u+th$. It remains to use multiplicative property: $[uv]_\alpha\le C[u]_\alpha[v]_\alpha$. The latter holds because 
$$
|u(x)v(x)-u(y)v(y)|\le |u(x)| |v(x)-v(y)|+|u(x)-u(y)||v(y)| \le 2|x-y|^\alpha [u]_\alpha [v]_\alpha $$
and similarly for the supremum part of the $C^\alpha$ norm:
$$
\sup_x|u(x)v(x)|\le \sup_x|u(x)| \sup_x|v(x)| \le [u]_\alpha [v]_\alpha $$